# What is the standard way to avoid both N+1 and the Cartesian Product issues while fetching collections with JPA

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, orm

When one has an entity with fields part of which are collections, one wishes to fetch the data with the smallest number of queries possible and using as less memory as possible.

The first problem is addressed by "join fetch" in JPQL queries (solving the N+1 problem).

However "join fetch" (as easily seen by inspecting the respective SQL query) causes the Cartesian product problem: each "row" which corresponds to the entity fields without multiplicities, is present in the returned result set with multiplicity N_1 x N_2 x ... x N_m, where N_1 is the multiplicity of the first collection, N_2 is the multiplicity of the second, and N_m is the multiplicity of the m-th collection, assuming that the entity has m fields which are collections.

Hibernate solves this problem with FetchMode.SUBSELECT (which, If I am not mistaken, makes m+1 queries, each of which returns no redundant data). What is the **standard** way to resolve this issue in JPA (it seems to me I cannot mix, at least in this case, JPA annotations with those of Hibernate)?

Comment: Actually, I think that `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` makes two queries: one to retrieve the parent, one to retrieve the associated children via an IN query.

Comment: @Tim I denote by m the number of fields of the entity which are collections, not the cardinality of these collections (I clarify it just in case my notation is misleading). If I am not mistaken, Hibernate will perform one query to retrieve the parent, plus a query with IN for each one of the m collections; thus, together, m+1 queries.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'd misread what you'd written.

Answer (score 8):

The **best way** is to replace collections with queries, especially when the expected size is large enough to lead to a performance issue:

1. You remove the bidirectional `@OneToMan`y side, leaving only the owning `@ManyToOne` side
2. You select the parent entity (e.g. `Country`) run queries like:

   ```
    select c from City c where c.country = :country
    select c from County c where c.country = :country
    select count(p), c.name from People p join p.country group by c.name
   ```

Comment: I changed the wording a little bit. All in all, the unlimited sized collections can cause serious performance issues, so currently there's no standard way to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to add @fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) or @fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) it dose not make any change i.e(still make join and not make subselect two quires it make all select in the same query)

Comment: Sorry for answering only now; try to take a look at  http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/ , there should be a working example of @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)

Answer (score 0):

When you try with

`entityManager.find(PoDetail.class, poNumber)`

you will have all the lists declared in the entities with `@OneToMany` initialized with Cartesian product no of times, which will have duplicates as well. Of course one can eliminate these duplicates by using `Set` but Set does not preserve the order of data insertion and when tried to display in View we have scrambled rows.

I solved this by using :

**NamedQueries with parameters** to avoid such fetching of Cartesian product of collections.

Doing so your view data will be as is with the persistent data insertion order.

Here is the sample code:

Parent Entity class: (It has more list fields, I am mentioning one here)

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="PO_DETAILS")
    @NamedQuery(name="PoDetail.findByPoNumber", query="SELECT p FROM PoDetail p where p.poNumber=:poNumber")
        public class PoDetail implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PO_NUMBER", unique=true, nullable=false, length=30)
    private String poNumber;

    @Column(name="ACTION_TAKEN", length=2000)
    private String actionTaken;

    .....

    //bi-directional one-to-many association to PcrDetail

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="poDetail", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<PcrDetail> pcrDetails;
```

Child Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PCR_DETAILS")
public class PcrDetail implements Serializable {

@Id
    @Column(name="PCR_NUMBER", unique=true, nullable=false, length=30)
    private String pcrNumber;

    @Column(name="CONTRACT_ID", length=30)
    private String contractId;
    .....

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PoDetail

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_PO_NUMBER", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private PoDetail poDetail;
```

JPA DAO class:

```
    public PoBean getPoDetails(PoBean poBean) {

    PoDetail poDetail = poBean.getPoDetail();
    String poNumber = poDetail.getPoNumber();
    entityManagerFactory = JpaUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    try {

        try {

            poDetail = (PoDetail) entityManager
                    .createNamedQuery("PoDetail.findByPoNumber")
                    .setParameter("poNumber", poNumber).getSingleResult();

        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            poBean.setStatusCode(PopVO.ERROR);
            poBean.setErrorMessage("No PO details foun with PO Number : "
                    + poNumber);
        }

        return poBean;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        poBean.setStatusCode(PopVO.ERROR);
        poBean.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());

        return poBean;

    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems to me that you misunderstood what the Cartesian product problem is; try to take a look, for example, at http://learningviacode.blogspot.it/2012/08/fetch-join-and-cartesian-product-problem.html .

Comment: this is bad answer. you should use lazy load in one to many mapping. Use eager is a bad practis